# How to mock a post commit hook in github, for a repo that is not owned

Tags: git, github, post-commit-hook

Id like to enable a post commit hook on a repository that I do not own.  Is this possible via forking + tracking ?  Or is there another way to enable watching commits of another repository so that your own repository can enable custom post-commit hooks ?

For context: In this case - I'm an active developer on a project which I don't have admin rights to, which is open source and on github, so I'd like to have some custom post-commit hooks for myself without having to force the admin to install them.

I assume that git tracking is the idiomatic way to go about this - but Im not sure how github works when it comes to cascading commit events downwards.

Comment: post-commit hooks are client-side, so why don't you clone and set up the commit hook?

Comment: i thought they were server side.  whats the server side hook called?

Comment: ahhh... post-receive vs post-commit .

Comment: In any case, @CharlesB the solution you propose does not track other peoples commits.

Comment: commits are a client side action. There is no way to track an event occurring on someone else's local machine unless you have them set something up. Theres no way you can even know someone committed something until after they have pushed those commits.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the hook?  Could an alternative be a post-update hook on a machine you control coupled with something like a cron job for fetching updates?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, you can add an other remote repository in your local working dir :
1° link your working dir to the official repo (that way you will have both origin and official as remote repository)
    $ git remote add official git@github.com:official/repo
2° update your local master branch (or whatever)
    $ git fetch official && git merge official/master --ff 
3° push the changes in your own github account
    $ git push origin master

Now, you can automate this (the 2°) in a script which can be executed each time you receive a mail from github for that particular repo, or maybe it's easier to create a cron for that(with an optionnal check to try to merge only if clean dir).

The things to automate is only the "fetch & merge" thing, maybe you can just keep doing that manually